# How can I get correct space padding in java

Tags: java, string, formatting

I am trying to align all the names and numbers neatly with a spacing of 10 characters, but the formatting is messed up for some reason.

I used .trim() to get rid of the white spaces, and I try to use , as a separator, but the formatting is still messed up.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class StraightAs {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            // TODO: the line of code below is a checkstyle violation.
            // Figure out what the violation is and what you can do to fix it.
            // You can find instructions on how to run checkstyle in the
            // homework instructions
            System.out.println("Welcome to Java. Are you ready to take on the challenge?\nMake sure you read and fully understand the provided instructions and the comments in this file to ensure you get full credit for your work.");



            showUsage("");
        } else if (args.length == 3) {
            // The code you write in processGrades will be called when your
            // program is run with two additional command line arguments, for
            // example: java StraightAs myfile.csv myseparator
            processGradesFromFile(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
        } else {
            showUsage(args[0]);
        }
    }


    /**
     * This method will create a grade histogram from a given csv file.
     * In your implementation, you need to read in the data, parse it as a CSV
     * formatted file with the provided data separator string, and output the
     * processed data to your terminal window. See the @param tags below for
     * more details on each parameter
     *
     * @param filename      the filename of the CSV file to read and process
     *                      data from
     * @param separator     the CSV file's given data separator. This is the
     *                      string constant that your program should use to
     *                      split each line in the CSV file into data fields
     *                      for parsing
     * @param displayMode   the type of output your program should show. We
     *                      define three modes: TABLE, HIST, and BOTH. See the
     *                      homework instructions for information on each of
     *                      these modes
     * @throws Exception    Don't worry about what this means yet. You'll learn
     *                      about exceptions later in the course =)
     */
    public static void processGradesFromFile(
            String filename, String separator, String displayMode)
        throws Exception {
        // TODO implement me!
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filename));



        while(scan.hasNextLine()){

            System.out.printf("%10s\n", scan.nextLine().trim());

        }

        scan.close();

        if (displayMode == "TABLE"){

        } else if (displayMode == "HIST") {





        } else if (displayMode == "BOTH"){

        }


    }
```

Comment: Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: Also read the comments regarding the csv nature of the file and separator. You'll need to account for that. The 10 is not spacing between fields - it is the minimum amount of spaces to set aside for each printed value. You are passing 1 string encompassing the entire line to be printed, unseparated.

Comment: So, displayMode.equalsIgnoreCase("TABLE") would be the correct way of doing that part?

Comment: we were told not to hard code anything for the separator part so I'm unsure about what to do for that

Comment: I wonder what you expect to get with `%-10s\n`. You print the String, pad the rest of the 10 chars with withspaces and then add a hardcoded linebreak ... so what is the point of adding these whitespaces? Do you may mean `%10s\n`?

Comment: having the %-10s\n allows the white space before the names in the file to disappear, http://prntscr.com/e2xqx2 , The top output is with the %-10s\n, and the bottom half output is with the %10s\n

Comment: I know the differences of both, but your posted code doesn't produce the first lines in that picture. How do you expect it to work? You read one whole line and then print that one line .. where do you expect the additional whitespaces to appear? Where should they appear?

Comment: I updated the code to include the rest, but basically the assignment is to read, parse, and format CSV files, and so I thought that the printf I made would add the spacing between the names and the numbers since thats what I saw from examples. It isnt really working, and im honestly pretty lost. Its my first actual Computer Science course and its a bit more difficult than I thought. 

I thought that the trim method would remove the whitespaces that are in the lines of the files, and then the printf %-10s\n would add the spaces. At least, thats what I thought would happen

Comment: It's so hard to guess about your output with incomplete code :) can you please display your output here?

Comment: Ya, this is the output with all the parameters! http://prntscr.com/e2yiai

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

Are you not allowed of tabbing? with "\t"? For sure you'll prefer it rather than adding 10 spaces between them. Adding 10 spaces will lose your format base on the length of the names

**THIS WILL DO ON YOUR WHILE**

```
    while(scan.hasNextLine())
    {
        String[] splitted = scan.split(",");

        for(int i = 0; i<splitted.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%s\t\n", splitted[i].trim());
        }
        System.out.println(""); //for new line, or else print("\n");
    }
```

**FULL FORMAT**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class StraightAs 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        if (args.length == 0) 
        {
            // TODO: the line of code below is a checkstyle violation.
            // Figure out what the violation is and what you can do to fix it.
            // You can find instructions on how to run checkstyle in the
            // homework instructions

            System.out.println("Welcome to Java. Are you ready to take on the challenge?\nMake sure you read and fully understand the provided instructions and the comments in this file to ensure you get full credit for your work.");

            showUsage("");
        }

        else if (args.length == 3) 
        {
            // The code you write in processGrades will be called when your
            // program is run with two additional command line arguments, for
            // example: java StraightAs myfile.csv myseparator
            processGradesFromFile(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
        }

        else 
        {
            showUsage(args[0]);
        }
    }


    /**
     * This method will create a grade histogram from a given csv file.
     * In your implementation, you need to read in the data, parse it as a CSV
     * formatted file with the provided data separator string, and output the
     * processed data to your terminal window. See the @param tags below for
     * more details on each parameter
     *
     * @param filename      the filename of the CSV file to read and process
     *                      data from
     * @param separator     the CSV file's given data separator. This is the
     *                      string constant that your program should use to
     *                      split each line in the CSV file into data fields
     *                      for parsing
     * @param displayMode   the type of output your program should show. We
     *                      define three modes: TABLE, HIST, and BOTH. See the
     *                      homework instructions for information on each of
     *                      these modes
     * @throws Exception    Don't worry about what this means yet. You'll learn
     *                      about exceptions later in the course =)
     */

    public static void processGradesFromFile(
            String filename, String separator, String displayMode)
        throws Exception 
    {

        // TODO implement me!

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filename));

        while(scan.hasNextLine())
        {
            String[] splitted = scan.split(",");

            for(int i = 0; i<splitted.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.printf("%s\t\n", splitted[i].trim());
            }
            System.out.println(""); //for new line, or else print("\n");
        }

        scan.close();

        if (displayMode.equalsIgnoreCase("TABLE"))
        {
        } 

        else if (displayMode.equalsIgnoreCase("HIST")) 
        {
        }

        else if (displayMode.equalsIgnoreCase("BOTH"))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**END OF EDIT**

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

why not to put an empty string but with + "N" space before your scanned line to achieve the format you want? :)

```
    while(scan.hasNextLine())
    {
        System.out.printf("%10s%s\n", "", scan.nextLine().trim());
    }

    //%10s to add 10 space
    //%s for your scanned nextLine()
    //.trim() to trim your input
```

Comment: This code added space on the very left of the output, like this http://prntscr.com/e2yii3 . What I was trying to do was have it look a bit like this, http://prntscr.com/e2yiq0. 

I'm thinking maybe I should use a delimiter to try and remove that comma afterwards? I'll keep trying.

Comment: Thank you so much though for helping!

Comment: but you can't actually have that format since you have \n already before the next line though

Comment: i'll do the formatting but please inform me in this comment if you already done it

Comment: are they constant of 2 strings per line? is it allowed to make some brute force coding?

Comment: I havent done it yet, brute forcing is ok im pretty sure

Comment: I thought you gave up here :D I stopped making it because you're not responding :D anyway, I'm editing now my answer :) hope it helps your work